# How to display the new list from local storage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

How do I display the new list from local storage? When the user inputs a new search, that displays fine, and get's added to the localstorage. However it doesn't show the updated list in the last requests on the website. Currently it only shows it when refreshing the website. So basically how do I re-run / re-display the new and updated list from localstorage? Here's a fiddle of the [HTML](https://jsfiddle.net/5mqsw3z2/)

```
// Local Storage
function SaveDataToLocalStorage(data) {
  var a = [];
  // Parse the serialized data back into an aray of objects
  a = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('last-requests')) || [];
  // Push the new data (whether it be an object or anything else) onto the beggining of the array
  a.unshift(data)
  // If more than 5 requests remove (pop) last request
  if (a.length > 5) {
    a.pop()
  }
  // Re-serialize the array back into a string and store it in localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('last-requests', JSON.stringify(a));
displayLastRequests()
};
```

```
// Displays last 5 requests/searches
function displayLastRequests() {
  const lastReq = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('last-requests'))
  console.log(lastReq)
  // for loop request
  for (req of lastReq) {
    var clone = $($("#last-request-template").html());
    clone.appendTo(".last-requests");
    clone.find(".cityname").text(req.city_name);
    clone.find(".cityweather").text(req.weather);
    clone.find(".imgs").attr('src', req.imgurl);
    clone.find(".citytemp").text(req.city_temp + " °C");
    clone.find(".citywind").text(req.city_wind + " m/s");
  }
};
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean, I've tried to run `displayLastRequests` after `SaveDataToLocalStorage` and outside it. @EmielZuurbier

Comment: You're not removing the old contents of `.last-requests` before you append in the loop.

Comment: Do you see the expected results in `console.log(lastReq)`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes exactly, I don't know how to remove the old contents of `displayLastRequests` . Do you have any ideas?

Comment: `$(".last-requests").empty()`

Comment: Yes it works fine in the console / localStorage. The only problem is displaying the correct searches on the site   @Barmar

Comment: `$(".last-requests").empty()` worked perfectly, thank you so much @Barmar

Comment: And even if you don't know about that, isn't `.html("")` obvious? That's all that `.empty()` does.